# Lazy HighCharts and Loading Json Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, highcharts, lazy-high-charts

I'm using LazyHighCharts and trying to collect json data to display only the last 24hrs, but it's not displaying the data, just the date but only once (there should be a temperature each hour of the day).

data structure

```
{"status": "ok", "data": [{"2014-06-16 16:00:00": 24.2},{"2014-06-17 12:00:00": 30.2},{"2014-06-18 17:00:00": 42.9}]} etc
```

Controller

```
@data = JSON.parse(open(@temperature.url).read)

dates = []
temps = []

@data['data'].each do |data|
 dates << data.keys
 temps << data.values
end 

@graph = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('graph') do |f|
 f.chart(:height => '400')
 f.yAxis [:title => {:text => "Temperature", :margin => 20, style: { color: '#333'}}]
 f.series(:pointInterval => 1.hour, :pointStart => 30.day.ago, :type => 'area', :name => '24hrs', :data => [[dates, temps]])
 f.options[:xAxis] = { :minTickInterval => 24 * 3600 * 1000, :type => "datetime", :dateTimeLabelFormats => { day: "%b %e"}, :title => { :text => nil }, :labels => { :enabled => true } }
end
```

Image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to convert your datetime object to the JS milliseconds convention, just call

```
DateTime.now.to_i*1000
```

or in your case

```
def index
  @data = {"status" => "ok", "data" => [{"2014-06-16 16:00:00" => 24.2},{"2014-06-17 12:00:00" => 30.2},{"2014-06-18 17:00:00" => 42.9}]}
  d = []
  @data['data'].each do |data|
    d << [DateTime.parse(data.keys.first).to_i*1000, data.values.first]
  end 

  @chart = LazyHighCharts::HighChart.new('chart') do |f|
    f.chart(:height => '400')
    f.yAxis [:title => {:text => "Temperature", :margin => 20, style: { color: '#333'}}]
    f.xAxis(type: 'datetime')
    f.series(:type => 'area', :name => '24hrs', :data => d)
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but now the data is not showing, still only 1 date on the x axis and no data. it's like it's not looping through.

Comment: I changed the answer with my minimal demo controller which works for me with current lazy_high_charts and rails 4.1.6.

Answer (score 1):

Your dates should be timestamps (time in miliseconds like 12323311000) not in the form like this: "2014-06-16 16:00:00" So you need to convert it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry for the lateness in reply. I'm a bit stumped on the conversion part. Do you have any references? Cheers.

Comment: Unfortunatley Im not familiar with the Ruby